# "Мне права нету"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать вместо "у меня нет права" "мне права нету"?

Comment: В стихотворной форме - да, можно.

Comment: Лучше сказать "мне право не дано".

Answer (score 1):

В устной речи в бытовом разговоре возможно, в письменной нежелательно.

"Мне права нет" - разговорная конструкция, вполне употребима и в поэзии, но вот "нету" - это уже просторечие, а поэзии свойственна скорее торжественная архаика, но не просторечия, если это не речь неграмотного крестьянина.